# What is wrong with this banner-in-chest command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been trying to make this command run, from https://minersneedcoolshoes.com.

I used the banner generator, made a bunch of banners, and clicked export to chest. This command is for MC 1.12, which everytime i fix one of the "errors" throws a new one, and it
goes on like this forever, I can't figure out is wrong here.

Command:

```
/setblock ~0 ~1 ~0 minecraft:chest 0 replace {Items:[{id:minecraft:banner,Count:1,Slot:0,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Base:15,Patterns:[{Pattern:gra,Color:14},{Pattern:gru,Color:5},{Pattern:bri,Color:0}]}}},{id:minecraft:banner,Count:1,Slot:1,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Base:15,Patterns:[{Pattern:gra,Color:5},{Pattern:gru,Color:1},{Pattern:bri,Color:0}]}}},{id:minecraft:banner,Count:1,Slot:2,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Base:0,Patterns:[{Color:5,Pattern:rd},{Color:5,Pattern:lud},{Color:0,Pattern:ts},{Color:0,Pattern:hhb},{Color:0,Pattern:cs},{Color:0,Pattern:ms}]}}},{id:minecraft:banner,Count:1,Slot:3,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Base:0,Patterns:[{Pattern:mc,Color:14},{Pattern:sku,Color:1},{Pattern:flo,Color:0},{Pattern:moj,Color:0},{Pattern:bs,Color:0},{Pattern:ts,Color:0}]}}},{id:minecraft:banner,Count:1,Slot:4,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Base:9,Patterns:[{Pattern:flo,Color:0},{Pattern:mr,Color:9},{Pattern:mc,Color:0}]}}},{id:minecraft:banner,Count:1,Slot:5,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Base:0,Patterns:[{Pattern:gru,Color:12},{Pattern:cre,Color:5}]}}},{id:minecraft:banner,Count:1,Slot:6,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Base:15,Patterns:[{Pattern:gru,Color:12},{Pattern:cre,Color:5}]}}},{id:minecraft:banner,Count:1,Slot:7,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Base:0,Patterns:[{Pattern:flo,Color:15},{Pattern:mr,Color:0},{Pattern:mc,Color:15}]}}},{id:minecraft:banner,Count:1,Slot:8,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Base:11,Patterns:[{Pattern:flo,Color:14},{Pattern:mr,Color:11},{Pattern:mc,Color:14}]}}},{id:minecraft:banner,Count:1,Slot:9,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Base:0,Patterns:[{Pattern:flo,Color:14},{Pattern:mr,Color:0},{Pattern:mc,Color:14}]}}},]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generator forgets to put `""`s around `minecraft:banner`, resulting in:

```
{id:minecraft:banner}
```

which is invalid syntax.

In reality, the `:` is part of the string, so you need to look for `id:minecraft:banner` everywhere, and replace it with:

```
{id:"minecraft:banner"}
```